# Google login on .NET backend with React application in frontend

Tags: reactjs, asp.net, axios, google-signin

**EDIT (Thank @possum)**
The code under work properly.

**TIMEWASTER ALERT**
In the option of .AddGoogle(), you can specify a custom callback. This is the callback used in the authentication mechanism between .AddGoogle and the frontend.
In other words, this callback is "internal" and not make by us.

The callback enpoint must are specify in ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties("Google", **callback url, endpoint after user signin**)

I have some issue to make functional a very simple function! Signin on my backend with google (and some other provider).
Before start, you have all of my apologize, the solution to my issue is probably evident for anyone with a good experience on react. It's my first project with react.

So I've read some articles on how integrate Google signin/signup on a backend with NET core and React in frontend. And easy I've read issues found here ...
The code in controller :

```
[HttpPost("google-login")]
[AllowAnonymous]
[OpenApiOperation("Login / Signup by an external provider.", "Connection with Google, Microsoft, etc")]
public IActionResult GoogleLogin()
{
    var redirectUrl = $"https://localhost:5001/api/authentication/google-login-callback";
    var properties = _authenticationService.ConstructHandleForGoogleLogin("Google", redirectUrl);

    return Challenge(
        properties,
        "Google");
}

[HttpGet("google-login-callback")]
[AllowAnonymous]
[OpenApiOperation("Callback of agent of login provider.", "Connection with Google, Microsoft, etc")]
public async Task<ActionResult> GoogleLoginCallback()
{
    var authenticateResult = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);
    throw new Exception();
}
```

The code in authentication service :

```
public AuthenticationProperties ConstructHandleForGoogleLogin(string provider, string redirectUrl)
{
    if (provider.ToLowerInvariant() != "google")
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Bad provider requested, this is only for Google");

    var properties = _signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(provider, redirectUrl);
    properties.AllowRefresh = true;

    return properties;
}
```

The code for the configuration :

```
    internal static class Startup
{
    private static readonly ILogger _logger = Log.ForContext(typeof(Startup));

    internal static IServiceCollection AddGoogleAuthentication(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration config)
    {
        _logger.Information("Third partie authentication enabled : {0}", "Google");

        services.AddOptions<AuthenticationGoogleSettings>()
            .BindConfiguration($"SecuritySettings:{nameof(AuthenticationGoogleSettings)}")
            .ValidateDataAnnotations()
            .ValidateOnStart();

        services
            .AddAuthorization()
            .AddAuthentication(authentication =>
            {
                authentication.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                authentication.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddCookie()
            .AddGoogle(googleOptions =>
            {
                googleOptions.ClientId = config["SecuritySettings:AuthenticationGoogleSettings:ClientId"];
                googleOptions.ClientSecret = config["SecuritySettings:AuthenticationGoogleSettings:ClientSecret"];
                //googleOptions.CallbackPath = "/api/authentication/google-login-callback"; <- TIMEWAST ALERT
                googleOptions.AuthorizationEndpoint += "?prompt=consent";
                googleOptions.AccessType = "offline";

                googleOptions.Scope.Add("profile");
                googleOptions.SignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
            });

        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Strict;
        });

        return services;
    }
}
```

The code in Frontend :

```
<form method='POST' action={`https://localhost:5001/api/authentication/google-login`} >
    <IconButton  
      type='submit'
      name='provider'
      value='Google'>
        <Iconify icon="eva:google-fill" color="#DF3E30" />
    </IconButton>
  </form>
```

Comment: You're not posting all your relevant code.  You're getting a CORS error because you're probably trying to do a POST to the redirect URL with a browser fetch instead of redirecting the browser to the redirect URL.

Comment: Hi @possum, thank for your answer. I've added the last part of my code to see everything on how the link is build (I think the part missing ?).

Comment: OK, I think I follow now.  You manually followed the link to the accounts login.  If I follow your code and server behavior, you should be redirecting the *browser* to your login endpoint, *not* doing an axios call, (so make an anchor tag with an `href` or manually change the window location) so that it can properly redirect you to google's login page which handles it from there.  You're probably losing some internal session which is why it's 500ing on the callback.  Try that and see what happens.

Comment: @possum I've tried something like this (I think?), I add this in the main post*
I've found a good tutorial, this one [link](https://pellerex.com/blog/google-auth-for-react-with-aspnet-identity)
The react side is a problem I think, and I don't find a sample or project exemple in github or other

Comment: You didn't from what I can see and I told you your problem is in the react side.  You need to remove the axios post and redirect the broswer instead

Comment: @possum I've updated the post and the code 
You have save my day, thank you !

Comment: @BenoitPotier I keep getting the following error on my redirect back to my application from google. An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
Exception: Correlation failed. Any idea on this?

Comment: @HeelMega I don't have at anytime an exception like this. But for the authentication by an external provider a cookies is make by asp.net, the correlation cookies. I suggest you to investigate in your browser console if everything's is good (maybe consent issue?), and in other case your cookies options. I hope this can help you..